# How do I configure IIS 7.5 to allow using a network share as an image src?

Tags: asp.net, iis7, iis

I have a web application that will be used internally that points to images on a network drive.

It works when I test it in VS, but the images don't load once published.

I'm sure it's a setting in IIS but I can't figure out what it is.

Each computer is already logged into the domain, and those who have access should be allowed to view the image.

I tried changing the authentication to impersonate, but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

For a URL, you need to escape the slashes and specify a protocol (file:// in this case). Example:

```
    <img src="file://///server01\fshare\dir1\dir2\my_img.jpg" />
```

Please note that we ended up with 5 slashes after the protocol (`file:`)

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered creating a mapped network drive on the local machine that IIS is on (i.e. \NetworkShare mapped to drive letter "X:") with appropriate permissions and then create a virtual directory under your web mapped to the new mapped drive (X:).

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to enable `Static Content` serving. As stated in [Microsoft - Deploying a Static Content Server (IIS 7)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732612%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) for this option:

> **Static Content** 
>   Allows the Web server to publish static Web file formats.

To do this:

1. Go to: 
   *Control Panel -> Programs and Features -> Turn Windows features on or off*
2. Check `Static Content` under: 
   *Internet Information Services -> World Wide Web Services -> Common HTTP Features*

   [image]

Also, see the second answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3771831/iis-7-5-no-images-css-js-showing) related question.